# Windows Re-image computer select drive

Tags: windows, windows-8

Okay, so if I'm attempting a reset via window image backup, how do I know what hard drive it will restore the image into? I've reached the prompt almost to the end, but at no point does it even tell me what drive it will write too.

the reason I ask is because I have my 240GB ssd (which is where I would like it to back up into) along with 4 3TB disks, which I hope it stays very far away from, I'm rather unsure whether or not to continue, or simply re-install windows from the disk and be able to safely select what drive will be written too.

I really want to know if this would be a safe procedure, as it would save me a few hours of having to then re install programs, but not at the risk of deleting data.

Answer (score -1):

In these situations I simply disconnect the power / data cables to the other drives if possible or disable their SATA ports using the BIOS utility. Better safe than sorry.

Comment: I had asked this question over on stackoverflow before I learned of super user, and I got the same answer... which is a perfectly fine answer... but seems like such a painful workaround.

Not to mention my backup partition is inside one of the 3TB drives, so that exposes the non backup partition as well.

Answer (score -1):

The second last screen should look like the one below and if you select the check box "Format and repartition disks" you'll have the option to exclude the disks that you don't want to be touched.

[image]

Comment: Why did you post two seemingly incomplete answers?

Comment: that option is greyed out...

Comment: Even after checking the box to format and repartition disks?